# sandboxd prohibits my custom backend to run on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, perl, sandbox, osx-yosemite, cups

I have made a custom CUPS backend in Perl. It works perfectly in 10.7-10.9, but 10.10 (Yosemite) apparently has a new sandbox feature that stops me from including a file from a subdir in "/opt".

Any suggestions are welcome!

Here is from the cups error_log:

```
Can't locate Net/IPP/IPP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::IPP::IPP module) (@INC contains: /opt/msipp [redacted] .) at /usr/libexec/cups/backend/msipp line 73.
```

Here is from the system log:

```
sandboxd[286]: ([11381]) perl5.18(11381) deny file-read-metadata /opt/msipp/Net/IPP/IPP.pm
```

The complete system log entry:

```
perl5.18(11381) deny file-read-metadata /opt/msipp/Net/IPP/IPP.pm

Process:         perl5.18 [11381]
Path:            /usr/bin/perl5.18
Load Address:    0x10dd8b000
Identifier:      perl5.18
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       x86_64 (Native)
Parent Process:  cupsd [10823]

Date/Time:       2014-10-09 00:15:41.756 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.10 (14A379a)
Report Version:  8

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8de28a6e stat$INODE64 + 10
1   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010de5241e
2   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010de519cc Perl_pp_require + 3076
3   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010de171ca Perl_runops_standard + 210
4   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010ddaf2cd Perl_call_sv + 938
5   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010ddabe46 Perl_call_list + 355
6   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010dda220f
7   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010dda1ef3 Perl_newATTRSUB_flags + 3620
8   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010dd9c9bf Perl_utilize + 747
9   libperl.dylib                   0x000000010ddd78ae Perl_yyparse + 2514
10  libperl.dylib                   0x000000010ddae0c6 perl_parse + 7886
11  perl5.18                        0x000000010dd8bccb main + 203
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8873d5c9 start + 1

Binary Images:
       0x10dd8b000 -        0x10dd8bfff  perl5.18 (103) <dd623cf6-275a-3bc8-bde0-09566702484d> /usr/bin/perl5.18
       0x10dd93000 -        0x10deb7ff7  libperl.dylib (103) <8fc40e39-a06c-3454-8ada-f82bbfd179f2> /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib
    0x7fff8873a000 -     0x7fff8873dff7  libdyld.dylib (353.2.1) <19faf435-c165-3374-9def-d7bba7d61db6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8de11000 -     0x7fff8de2efff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.1.97) <93e0e0a9-75b6-3904-bb4e-4bc7c05f4b6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the dependencies from /opt/msipp to /usr/share/cups/msipp

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to Yosemite GM 3.0. It resolved the issue in my case.